# Net Framework - SOAP Service en IIS: problema de memory leaks, Que opciones hay para poder detectar el proceso problematico?

Tags: c#, net, framework

Tengo un problema con un servicio SOAP desarrollado en .net framework 4.8, el cual esta desplegado en un IIS. Este es un servicio muy grande al cual le llegan solicitudes de varios puntos, es decir es consumido por un gran numero de otras aplicaciones. El problema de esto es que en determinados momentos y dias este servicio colapsa consumiendo todo la memoria y recursos del servidor, provando un apagado o reinicio del mismo.

Este tiene cientos de endpoind disponibles, de los cuales no se sabe cual o cuales son los conflictivos, me es imposible realizar una prueba por Debug , ya que las condiciones de produccion son muy complejas de producir por la gran cantidad de demanda que tiene y por que se consume desde muchas otras app disitintas

Me gustaria saber ante este caso, cual es la mejor alternativa para poder encontrar esa o esas funciones expuestas, que son las conflictivas, para luego, si hacer una test especificamente sobre esos metodos

Estaba pensando en colocar en cada uno de los metodos expuestos en el servicio, un log que registre tiempo y uso de memoria, y asi poder detectar en produccion cuando el servicio colpase , algo parecido a esto:

```
var timemonitor = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

try
{
    
    //bloque de codigo de una funcion expuesta del servicio


}
finally 
{
    timemonitor.Stop();
    long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
    Log.Info($"tiempo:{timemonitor.ElapsedMilliseconds}  memoria:{totalBytesOfMemoryUsed}");

}
```

Esto bloque de codigo tendria que ponerlo en cada una de los cientos de metodos expuestos del servicio.

¿Existe otra forma de monitorear, optener metricas de este servicio, mediante librerias o herramientas que no sean muy complejas de implementar? , Q alternativas hay o recomendaciones?

Gracias

Comment: (1) Lo primero es revisar el "visor de eventos" y ver si hay información útil.- (2) No debes descartar un problema de hardware, que cuando un sector de la memoria o del disco esta dañado produce un problema similar al que describes. (3) Tampoco debes descartar que sea otra aplicación la que cuelgue el servidor. (4) También puede ser culpa de una de las APP cliente que está mal desarrollada y le pega de sobre manera al servidor. (5) Si vas a hacer un log te recomiendo guardar los datos en formato CSV, que si no te vas a volver loco usando el bloc de notas

Comment: Justo vi un video y me acordé de tu pregunta https://youtu.be/qC_ioJQpv4E?t=984 (ver desde el minuto 16)